# Time complexity of nested loop: where does cn(n+1)/2 come from?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity

Consider the following loop:

```
   for (i =1; i <= n; i++) {
     for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        k = k + i + j; 
     } 
    }
```

The outer loop executes n times. For i= 1, 2, ..., the inner loop is executed one time, two times, and
n times. Thus, the time complexity for the loop is

```
 T(n)=c+2c+3c+4c...nc
     =cn(n+1)/2
     =c/2(n^2)+c/2n
     =O(n^2)..
```

Ok so I don't understand how the time complexity, T(n) even determines  c+2c+3c. etc.. and then cn(n+1)/2? Where did that come from?

Comment: See the answer with Sigma Notation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413458/time-complexity-for-loop/22416985).

Answer (score 4):

The sum 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n is equal to n(n+1)/2, which is the [Gauss series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html).  Therefore,

> c + 2c + 3c + ... + nc
>
> = c(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)
>
> = cn(n+1) / 2

This summation comes up a lot in algorithmic analysis and is useful to know when working with big-O notation.

Or is your question where the summation comes from at all?

Hope this helps!