# Time Complexity for loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, analysis

I was trying to find the time complexity for a for loop. below is loop detail.

```
for(int i=N;i>1;i=i/2)
{
   for(int k=0;k<i;k++){
     sum++;
   }
}
```

Below is any find for the problem. Please correct me if i am going worng.

Inner loop will be exceute `N+N/2+N/4+N/8....`

so `tn=ar^(n-1)`. So replacing `Tn=1`, `a=N` and `r=1/2`

```
1=N(1/2)^(n-1)
```

therefore

```
1/2N=(1/2)^n
```

So sum of inner loop is a GP. `Sn=a(1-r^n)/(1-r)`
Replacing `a=N,r=1/2`, we get

```
Sn=N(1-(1/2N))/(1-1/2)
```

therefore `Sn=2N-1`

I am not sure if complexity is `N`.

Please help

Thanks.

Comment: You would like to find out how much time this loop takes?

Comment: Just count the number of times the code in the inner loop is executed: `N + N/2 + N/4 + ...`

Comment: On a piece of paper, make two columns, with headers "N" and "count". When N=1, how many times is `sum++` executed? For N=2, 3, 4, etc.? This will give you a start, and if you have questions, you can at least show this attempt.

Comment: Is this homework? It smells like homework.

Comment: Actually I wouldn't really recommend what @Matt said as such (although *some* attempt is always better than *no* attempt for [so] questions) - having a bunch of values and mapping a function to that is not an easy task - rather write down how many times the inner loop executes for each iteration of the outer loop - this will give you something like `a + b + c + d + e + ...` (some of these will depend on `N`). Then you need to have a bit of familiarity with finding a formula for a sum, which gives you your answer.

Comment: @Dukeling If he were to directly write down the number of iterations by skipping your step, then he would probably be smart enough to write the function too :) Naturally what I suggested would lead him through and motivate your analysis; you have added additional clarity to this process. Our suggestions are compatible, not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @user3264197 You may want to take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it

Comment: @trogdor: You still need to know the sum formula for the geometric series

Comment: I did some analysis but i am not sure i am correct. Please find the detail.  inner loop will execute as N +N/2+N/4.... 1=N(1/2)^(n-1). therefore (1/2)^n=(1/2N).. Now, Sn=a(1-r^n)(1-r)..therefore Sn=2N-1. I am not sure if inner loop has time complexity of 2N-1.

Comment: @user3264197: You need to *show your own attempt* in the question. Please consult the help center for information on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @NiklasB. I wanted to give the asker a significant step to solve the problem without providing the complete answer, given the effort put in the question. Are you implying that I gave too much information, or that I should have posted the complete answer?

Comment: @trogdor: I just noted that it is probably not helpful to figure *that* part out, but I don't really care either

Comment: Thanks I will edit the question to show what attempt i have made.

Comment: @trogdor Personally I think you gave away too much, and too little (although OP seems to have a decent idea how to do it already, but assuming they didn't). A large part of this is to figure out each term of the sum, which you just gave away. Another part is finding the formula for the sum, which isn't really something you could just figure out if you don't have the maths knowledge to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the formal way (Sigma Notation) to infer the order of growth related to your algorithm (corroborated with experiments, using C's MinGW2.95 compiler).

[image]

Comment: I did not get the upper bound for second summation. How it is 2^i - 1. Could you please explain in detail

Comment: Well, you know that Sigma from i = k to n = (n - k) + 1? Since the terms of the second summation are independent, therefore, you just replace n with 2^{i - 1} and k with 0. I should end up with 2^{i - 1} - 0 + 1 (I will correct it).

Comment: Also, check this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5B+1+%5D+with+k+from+0+to+%282%5E%28i+-+1%29%29).

Comment: Also, check the last slide of [this .ppt](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt) for a thorough understand of logarithmic loops.

Comment: I'm 95% sure that anyone who understands this answer would've also fairly easily be able to determine the time complexity had they not seen it. As such, I don't think it's useful.

Comment: I expect that anyone who's comfortable with the mathematical notation used in this answer would fairly easily be able to figure out the time complexity of such a simple algorithm (assuming they know the basics about time complexity - if not, this answer won't help either). Perhaps more significantly, it's non-trivial to figure out how you actually got to your **first** step, and some (most) of the intermediate steps probably need a bit of an explanation.

Comment: I see your point. My aim is to allow interlocutors to discover that such a methodology does exist. I was thrilled when I discovered it, and where? in an algorithm analysis (and data structures) book of Mark Allen Weiss. I believe this is the right step toward the accurate learning path.

Comment: The solution underwent major alterations.